# Make thumbnails on product-category pages the same size [WooCommerce]

Tags: plugins

I have searched and didn't find a specific thread about my question. You can see what is happening on the following page: http://hubbardracinginc.com/product-category/98-02-camarofirebird/

The issue occurs on all product-category pages. The image thumbnails that are automatically created for products on WooCommerce are different sizes. My client wants them uniform. As of now, all I can think of is manually creating square thumbnails in Photoshop CC ( which would be very time consuming ).

I'm assuming there is a feature or plugin that will automatically make all thumbnails the same size? Just not seeing it..

Answer (score 2):

When I inspect your images I see http://cld.wthms.co/Ds8i

To make those images the same dimensions on that page you have 2 options,

1. make your images square before you load them
2. change the image settings in your WooCommerce -> settings -> catalog -> Image settings to match these settings http://cld.wthms.co/ICPu

With option 2 you will need to instal and run Regenerate Thumbnails from the WordPress plugin repository (I would link it but I need a 10 reputation to do that) to resize and crop your images.

Comment: Andrew, welcome to WPSE. Nice to have you here. Some additional notes to what you can read in the [help]: Please don't use signatures. SE uses the profile link already at the end of the question. Second (and more important), please don't use outside sources for images or code. That's help preventing link rot. I wanted to add your images in here, but it seems they're base64 decoded data strings, so the system behind SE (imgur) can't fetch them. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I will stop adding the signature, I just wanted to make sure that users are aware that I'm from Woo and my answer could be considered biased. I'll read up on adding images etc

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the "Hard Crop" setting in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Catalog.

Currently, it looks like "Hard crop" is not selected, so the images will display at their natural aspect ratios, thus some are taller than others.

Example screenshot with "hard crop" not selected: http://cld.wthms.co/Efbm

Example screenshot after selecting "hard crop" and running the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin: http://cld.wthms.co/pvXh